How can I deal with Lua garbage-collecting my userdata objects?
When making a Lua API for C code, I have made a function Thing that constructs a Lua userdata that returns a userdata for a C struct also called Thing.I also have a function List that returns a Lua userdata for a C struct called List, which contains C pointers for Thing objects.
If I have a Lua script:
local list = List()
local thing = Thing()
list:add(thing)
thing:setField(123)

return function()
    list:do_something()
end

and then, in my C code, I repeatedly lua_pcall the returned function, Lua's garbage collector will delete Thing. However, my list's C struct contains a pointer to thing, so thing should not be garbage-collected.
What would be the best way for me to be able to tell Lua to not garbage-collect thing? Would it be to (a) make list:add(thing) add a duplicate of thing, and not a pointer to thing itself? However, this would make the code a bit less convenient, since if thing was modified after list:add(thing), then list would not be changed.
Or would a better approach be to (b) make a wrapper function around Thing() like this:
function NewThing()
    local ret = {
        userdata: Thing(),
        dependencies: {}
    }
    function ret:add(thing)
        self.userdata:add(thing)
        dependencies[#dependencies+1] = thing
    end
end

I believe that this may work, but I do not know if having a Lua reference inside an table that is frequently used, will actually make the garbage collector not garbage-collect the userdata that that reference references. I am pretty sure it will make it safe, but I just want to be sure, and I want to know which approach would be better, or if there is a better alternate approach.

@AlanBirtles, the duplicated question is not appropriate. There are no gc_markroots and gc_mark in lua, they may come from another library. lua_ref has also been removed, lua only retains the luaL_ref API.
